# Socket под linux.

Tags: c++, linux, сокет

Здравствуйте. Хочу освоить сокеты под linux’ом на С++. я знаю, что сокеты были изначально написаны под unix, поэтому какая-то информация, но быть должна.
желательно книга.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почти во всех книгах по системному программированию в Линукс/Юникс есть раздел про сокеты. Рекомендую

1. Мэтью, Стоунс. Основы программирования в Linux.
2. Стивенс, Раго. Системное программирование в Unix.
3. Рочкинд. Программирование в Unix.
4. Kerrisk Michael. The Linux programming interface - моя самая любимая книга.

Есть классическая книга, посвященная целиком сетевому программированию в Юникс: Стивенс и др. Unix. Разработка сетевых приложений. Это самое полное изложение темы на данный момент.

Answer (score 1):

Дуглас Камер "Сети TCP/IP, Том 3. Разработка приложений типа клиент/сервер для Linux/POSIX"

Answer (score 1):

[Мне понравилась](http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html)

На самом деле достаточно кратко, очень о многом и примеры по делу.